# Iterating through dictionary lists with another list, and finding associated key of value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration, bioinformatics

I am writing code that modifies a 3 letter sequence at all 3 positions separately by exchanging that position with one of the following A, T, C, or G.

I have been able to create 3 lists where the initial element has either the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd position modified to one of the other 3 different letters.

I have written a dictionary that encodes each key (amino acid in this case) and it's corresponding codon sequences (which would be the elements I am modifying). .

Now, I aim to check each modified list's elements against this dictionary, and see which dict key they correspond to. I wish see if changes in the initial element change the resulting key associated with it.

I am unable to figure out how to proceed; how can I get the corresponding key for the values of my modified lists?

Here is my code so far:

```
thisdict = {
    "Arg": ['CGT', 'CGC','CGA','CGG'],
    "Phe": ['TTT','TTC'],
    "Leu": ['TTA','TTG','CTT','CTC','CTA','CTG'],
    "Ile": ['ATT','ATC'],
    "Met": ['ATA','ATG'],
    "Val": ['GTT','GTC','GTA','GTG'],
    "Ser": ['TCT','TCC','TCA','TCG','AGT','AGC'],
    "Pro": ['CCT,','CCC','CCA','CCG'],
    "Ala": ['GCT','GCC','GCA','GCG'],
    "Thr": ['ACT','ACC','ACA','ACG'],
    "Tyr": ['TAT','TAC'],
    "His": ['CAT','CAC'],
    "Gln": ['CAA','CAG'],
    "Asn": ['AAT','AAC'],
    "Lys": ['AAA','AAG'],
    'Asp': ['GAT','GAC'],
    "Glu": ['GAA','GAG'],
    "Cys": ['TGT','TGC'],
    "Trp": ['TGA','TGG'],
    "Gly": ['GGT','GGC','GGA','GGG'],
    "end(*)":['TAA','TAG','AGA','AGG'],
    }

def degenerated_sites(codon):
    print(thisdict)

    a_codon = list(codon)
    b_codon = list(codon)
    c_codon = list(codon)
    nucleotides = ['A','C','T','G']
    codons1=[]
    codons2=[]
    codons3=[]

    for i in range(len(nucleotides)):
        a_codon[0] = nucleotides[i]
        first_site = "".join(a_codon)
        codons1.append(first_site)
    for i in range (len(nucleotides)):
        b_codon[1] = nucleotides[i]
        second_site = "".join(b_codon)
        codons2.append(second_site)
    for i in range (len(nucleotides)):
        c_codon[2] = nucleotides[i]
        third_site = "".join(c_codon)
        codons3.append(third_site)
    codons1.remove(codon)
    codons2.remove(codon)
    codons3.remove(codon)
    
    print(codons1)
    print(codons2)
    print(codons3)

    for key, value in thisdict.items():
        for i in range(len(codons1)):
          if value == codons1[i]:
            print(key)
 #I have encoded the 64 codons with their asssocaited amino acids in a dictionary. I have changed the codon site 1, 2, and 3 and stored them in lists. Now I am trying to check if the initial amino acid has been chagned, and determine the degeneracy of each site of the codon (0-fold if any change in causes amino acid change, 2-fold if only 2 out of 4 nucleotides cause amino acid change, and 4-fold if any change in nucleotide results in no change of amino acid) 
   
degenerated_sites('CGT')
#I am confused why I am not getting any keys
```

My desired outcome is to have something like where the numbers above the codon indicate the degeneracy of that site, and extend this code for longer sequences.

```
004
CGT
```

Comment: You may benefit from explaining this problem independent of its application in Biology. Keep in mind a majority of the site likely wont understand parts of this problem as you've described it, but would understand "I have a dict of strings mapped to lists and I need to extract these things based on some characteristic".

Comment: @0x263A This is completely fair, and it was my doing in trying to be as descriptive of the issue as possible (and possibly hoping a bioinformatics fellow could guide me to a solution that is best applicable to my case.) I will update the question respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the item from the codon list is `in` the value of the dict, which is a list. So `if codons1[i] in value`

```
thisdict = {
    "Arg": ['CGT', 'CGC','CGA','CGG'],
    "Phe": ['TTT','TTC'],
    "Leu": ['TTA','TTG','CTT','CTC','CTA','CTG'],
    "Ile": ['ATT','ATC'],
    "Met": ['ATA','ATG'],
    "Val": ['GTT','GTC','GTA','GTG'],
    "Ser": ['TCT','TCC','TCA','TCG','AGT','AGC'],
    "Pro": ['CCT,','CCC','CCA','CCG'],
    "Ala": ['GCT','GCC','GCA','GCG'],
    "Thr": ['ACT','ACC','ACA','ACG'],
    "Tyr": ['TAT','TAC'],
    "His": ['CAT','CAC'],
    "Gln": ['CAA','CAG'],
    "Asn": ['AAT','AAC'],
    "Lys": ['AAA','AAG'],
    'Asp': ['GAT','GAC'],
    "Glu": ['GAA','GAG'],
    "Cys": ['TGT','TGC'],
    "Trp": ['TGA','TGG'],
    "Gly": ['GGT','GGC','GGA','GGG'],
    "end(*)":['TAA','TAG','AGA','AGG'],
    }

def degenerated_sites(codon):
    # print(thisdict)

    a_codon = list(codon)
    b_codon = list(codon)
    c_codon = list(codon)
    nucleotides = ['A','C','T','G']
    codons1=[]
    codons2=[]
    codons3=[]

    for i in range(len(nucleotides)):
        a_codon[0] = nucleotides[i]
        first_site = "".join(a_codon)
        codons1.append(first_site)
    for i in range (len(nucleotides)):
        b_codon[1] = nucleotides[i]
        second_site = "".join(b_codon)
        codons2.append(second_site)
    for i in range (len(nucleotides)):
        c_codon[2] = nucleotides[i]
        third_site = "".join(c_codon)
        codons3.append(third_site)
    codons1.remove(codon)
    codons2.remove(codon)
    codons3.remove(codon)
    
    for key, value in thisdict.items():
        for i in range(len(codons1)):
          if codons1[i] in value:   # this is the magic line
            print("key found!!!!", end=" ")
            print(key)
   
degenerated_sites('CGT')
```

Comment: Using this method worked well for me!

Answer (score 0):

At the following line:

```
if value == codons1[i]:
```

It looks like you are comparing a single codon to a list of codons, so you are never getting a match.

Try instead:

```
if codons1[i] in value:
```

I tried this and it seemed to work

```
Ser
Cys
Gly
```